# Possibility of creating an Amazon AWS EC2 instance from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create an EC2 instance (say of OmniOS) from CLI in my Linux. As per my understanding, it is seeming pretty much straight forward to launch an instance but I am skeptical about a possibility to create one instance due to the variables involved, possibly.
However, if it possible, it would be helpful for me to know how to do that. I've exhausted the available commands and nothing seems befitting for that to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-9fbbfaf5 --key-name key2 --security-groups mysecuritygroup --count 1 --instance-type t1.micro` where `ami-9fbbfaf5` is the ami for image, `key2` is my key name and `mysecuritygroup` is the name of security group.

Please ask if required to be more descriptive. I can alternatively, even link to my tutorial page where I have pretty exhaustively explained this.